# How to Add two Data tables in one Crystal Report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm Trying to add two data tables to Crystal Report, 
I insert two sub report in my crystal report and i added 1 data set which contains two data tables , but how to pass two data tables to sub report by code.

**Note that:** 2 data tables are generated by query not table from database.

```
        Dim Stmt1 As String = "select C_Code,C_name,Units from Courses where St_year like 'First' and C_Department like '%" & Label16.Text & "%' "
        Dim adp1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(Stmt1, con)
        Dim ds1 As New DataSet
        adp1.Fill(ds1)
        Dim dt1 = ds1.Tables(0)

        Dim Stmt2 As String = "select C_Code,C_name,Units from Courses where St_year like 'Second' and C_Department like '%" & Label16.Text & "%' "
        Dim adp2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(Stmt2, con)
        Dim ds2 As New DataSet
        adp2.Fill(ds2)
        Dim dt2 = ds2.Tables(0)

        Dim reportDocument As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        reportDocument = New RptResultsCR

        reportDocument.Subreports("Subreport1").SetDataSource(dt1)
        reportDocument.Subreports("Subreport2").SetDataSource(dt2)

        RptCourse.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument

        RptCourse.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use following line

```
RptDocument.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(ds1.Tables(0))
```

Comment: Edit: This is my Code so far. but it's not working.

Comment: your reportdocumnt is empty. you must load a rpt file. bevor you assign datasources.

Comment: Could u explain more?

Comment: The datasource of your documnet has to be the exact same in your dataset. if you added a table called employe with three columns name, firstname, age, your table that you supply as Datasource to the report. Crystal is there a little bit tricky. I personally create a dataset with all Tables. create a xml file from that dataset  and use that xml file as datasource to create my rpt file.this i load into the rptdoc and add that dataset as dataspurce